# Finding Largest String in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

// Im trying to find the largest String in my ArrayList and print it out and      also to include what index the largest element resides at and to print that to screen too. Im just wondering where Im going wrong.

Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;                  
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArraylistString
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
    // Instance of Scanner class
      Scanner keyboardIn = new Scanner(System.in);

   // Declare an array list of Strings
      ArrayList<String> Str = new ArrayList<>();
   // Add names to ArrayList
      Str.add("Jim Bob");
      Str.add("Bobby Jones");
      Str.add("Rob Stiles");
      int largestString = Str.size();
      int index = 0;

   // Use for loop to print out elements from ArrayList
      for(int i = 0; i < Str.size(); i++)
      {  // Test which String is the largest
         if(Str[i].size() > largestString)
         {
            largestString = Str[i].size();
            index = i;
         }

      } 
      // Output largest String and index it was found at
      System.out.println("Index " + index + " "+ Str[index] + " " + "is the largest and is size " + largestString);  

   }

}
```

Comment: You could start by identifying how your program is misbehaving.

Comment: think what initial value should `largestString` have if you are trying to maximize it.

Comment: What do you mean by "largest string"?

Comment: This wouldn't compile at all. `Str[i]` is not a proper way to access a `List`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try these code . Here i am trying with get() to access the ArrayList  elements, which is working correctly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;                  
import java.util.ArrayList;

class ArraylistString
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<String> Str = new ArrayList<String>();
        Str.add("Jim Bob");
        Str.add("Bobby Jones");
        Str.add("Rob Stiles");
        int largestString = Str.get(0).length();
        int index = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < Str.size(); i++)
        {
            if(Str.get(i).length() > largestString)
            {
                largestString = Str.get(i).length();
                                index = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Index " + index + " "+ Str.get(index) + " " + "is the largest and is size " + largestString);  

    }

}
```

Answer (score 36):

You can also use `java.util.Collections.max` or the `Stream` version:

**Java 8**

```
String max = Collections.max(strings, Comparator.comparing(String::length)); // or s -> s.length()
```

**OR**

```
String max = strings.stream().max(comparing(String::length)).get();
```

**Prior Java 8**

```
String max = Collections.max(Str, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {          
        return o1.length() - o2.length();
    }
});
```

Then

```
 System.out.println("Index " + arr.indexOf(max) + " " + max + " " + "is the largest and is size " + max.length());
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. Only one limitation with the logic is if there is more than one string having max length for example "abcd" and "abca" then too it will return only one result.

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct idea, but wrong syntax. In Java, only arrays support the `[]` syntax. An `ArrayList` isn't an array, it's a class that implements the `List` interface, and you should use the `get` method to access its members. Similarly, a `String` doesn't have a `size()` method, it has a `length()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I would set your `largestString` variable to your first `String` that you add:

```
int largestString = Str.get(0).length();
```

Then you should use the following to check for the largest `String`:

```
if(Str.get(i).length() > largestString) {
    largestString = Str.get(i).length();
    index = i;
}
```

You cannot index into an `ArrayList` with [] as you were trying to do.

I would also suggest better variable names. If I saw `Str` as a variable I would think it was a `String`. Maybe try `strList` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

**From Java-8 and onwards:**

```
    List<Integer> numList = Arrays.stream(Str).map(String::length).collect(Collectors.toList());
    Integer m = numList.stream().mapToInt(i->i).max().orElse(4000);  //get strings with their length
    int k = numList.indexOf(m);  //index of String with Maximum Length
    System.out.println(Str.get(k)); //get your longest string
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Java 8:**

```
Optional<String> op = Str.stream().sorted((e1,e2)-> e1.length() > e2.length() ? -1 :1).findFirst();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -2):

What are you getting as output?

also, the line

```html
int largestString = Str.size()
```

is setting largestString as the number of elements in the array Str so that may cause errors. I would set it to 0 or even -1 as a baseline, or maybe Str[0].size() so that you can start your for loop with your first element as your baseline.

EDIT:

I didn't even realize this was Java so like what people are saying, you cannot use the [] operator as you can in most languages and you should use string.length() not str.size()

Comment: Not a valid answer.