# accepting string in arraylist and returning each alphabet

Tags: java

I have a code that takes string parameter with the `nextLine()` function and pass 
to some function that returns the longest word.

I want to know if it is possible to use `ArrayList` and then access each 
alphabet with index so that I can tell how many words are there in the string 
and compare them later so that I can return the longest word.

Here is how I 
started. It works fine with the typical array but the typical array needs predefined size.

```
package senay;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    static String LongestWord(String sen) {
     ArrayList test = new ArrayList();     
     test.add(sen);
     System.out.println(test.substring(0,1));
     \\ it doesn't recongnize substring 
    return sen;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList testarray= new ArrayList();
    System.out.println(testarray.add("enter sentence"));    
    System.out.println(LongestWord(s.nextLine()));
}
```

Comment: `test` is an `ArrayList` , it doesn't have a `substring` method .

Comment: Your code does not even work for the sized based array either. You have to access the elements by their indexes. e.g. `test.get(0).substring`

Comment: HINT: Start with `String[] words = sen.split("\\s+");` to split up your sentence into words.

Comment: What string is the longest: A or Z?

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned by Berger in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49915739/accepting-string-in-arraylist-and-returning-each-alphabet#comment86847031_49915739) and by Murat K. in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49915739/accepting-string-in-arraylist-and-returning-each-alphabet#comment86847044_49915739), your `test` object is an instance of ArrayList. But ArrayList does not have a method called `subString()`, that's why it tells you it's not recognized.

[`subString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) is a method of String. So you need first to get a String before calling subString on it. The String you are manipulating is `sen` so you can call `sen.subString()`. Or if you want to call it on another String that is store in your ArrayList, use the method [`get(index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)) to obtain the String you want and call Substring on it : `test.get(index).subString()`

---

To inprove your code, ArrayList is a typed object, it means you can define what type of object it will contains. So you should (it's recommended) define that your ArrayList will contain String. `ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();`

Answer (score 0):

You've to write like this :

```
System.out.println(((String)test.get(0)).substring(0,1));
```

inside `LongestWord` method. As `test.get(0)` will return first object in arraylist which you need to typecast to String before calling it's substring method.

Answer (score 0):

**`Array`**

```
// Split all words from input sentence
String[] array = string.split("\\s+");

// count the number of words
int total = array.length;
```

You can get the longest `String` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725296/finding-the-longest-string-in-an-array-of-strings)

**`ArrayList`**

```
// Split all words from input sentence
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(string.split("\\s+")));

// count the number of words
int total = list.size();
```

You can get the longest `String` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32593820/finding-largest-string-in-arraylist)